# How to disable previous and next numbers in number picker (android)

Tags: android, numberpicker

To enable number picker I use this code:

```
    final NumberPicker numberPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
    numberPicker.setMaxValue(100);       
    numberPicker.setMinValue(1);         
    numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
```

But the thing is that I want number picker to look as on the screenshot only when I'm scrolling it, and when it is static(remeins untouched) I want it to show only picked number, without the one that goes before and after the current number. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a TextView or button that is visible by defalult, and a NumberPicker that is invisible by default, but is on top of the text view in layout XML. Then, setOnClickListener or setOnFocusChangeListener to the text view that will change visibility of the NumberPicker.

You need to define some logic of when to hide the NumberPicker again. I would suggest to hide it when it looses focus, or if after some time (few seconds) its value does not change.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this will work, but you can extend `NumberPicker` class like so:

```
public class MyNumberPicker extends NumberPicker {

    private float bottomFadingEdgeStrength = 1.0f;
    private float topFadingEdgeStrength = 1.0f;

    public MyNumberPicker(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected float getBottomFadingEdgeStrength() {
        return bottomFadingEdgeStrength;
    }

    @Override
    protected float getTopFadingEdgeStrength() {
        return topFadingEdgeStrength;
    }

    void setTopFadingEdgeStrength(float strength){
        topFadingEdgeStrength = strength;
    }

    void setBottomFadingEdgeStrength(float strength){
        bottomFadingEdgeStrength = strength;
    }
}
```

And then, by listening scroll events, set fading edges strength depending on the scroll state:

```
final MyNumberPicker np = new MyNumberPicker(this);
np.setOnScrollListener(new NumberPicker.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChange(NumberPicker view, int scrollState) {
        if (scrollState == NumberPicker.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL){
            np.setBottomFadingEdgeStrength(0.9f);
            np.setBottomFadingEdgeStrength(0.9f);
        } else if (scrollState == NumberPicker.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
            np.setBottomFadingEdgeStrength(1.0f);
            np.setBottomFadingEdgeStrength(1.0f);
        }
        //also you can handle SCROLL_STATE_FLING if you want
    }
});
```

Comment: No,no,no,no,no. I don't want to make it invisible, I want it to disappear.

Comment: @OleksandrSokil what's the difference except the fact, that even they are invisible, they will still use some space?

Comment: THis thing doesnt work. Well it changes number picker to this:https://www.dropbox.com/s/vpritrqe6uqmid3/device-2014-05-09-163557.png, but i can't change number, it is always thero (number picker is always idle)

Comment: They are still visible. How can I make it totally 0 alpha?